# Filter by Custom Taxonomy AND Custom Field

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I'd like to give my users the possibility to filter the posts by Taxonomy Terms AND Custom Field values.

Like so:

```
[tax]Country:[terms]
[tax]Company:[terms]

[field]Price:[values]
```

Filtering by Custom field range would be awesome.

At the moment I am filtering my posts with query multiple taxonomies plugin and looking for a solution to get a combined query of custom taxonomies and custom fields.

Comment: Filter where? Front end? Admin? This is commonly called "faceted search", you can start by doing some research in related plugins.

Comment: The filter should appear in the front end. Thanks for the tip on faceted search, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a solution for my scenario.

I combined those two plugins to filter by custom taxonomy and custom field:

Query Multiple Taxnomies http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/
Custom Query Fields http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-query-fields/

I changed the QMT Plugin template by adding the possibility to choose several custom fields and do a combined query.

The URL now looks as follows:

/?qmt%5BTAXONOMY1%5D%5B%5D=1532&price_min=400&price_max=600/

Greetings!

I recently enhanced my filter, making it a little bit cleaner, faster and less complicated as you dont't have to edit any plugin code. If you are interested, just get in touch.